# Adding Exit Animation on a Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am using the animate.css animations [found here](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/). And I am trying to use the window.onbeforeunload functionality in JavaScript. It works on Firefox, but I can't get it to work with chrome. Is there a more compatible way to do this. My code so far is imbedded in the html file just so I can figure this out, but the accomplishments id is for an aside and the class "animated fadeOutLeft" is used to call the animation, which works. I just want it to wait until the page is going to another internal link before it does that.

**MY CODE**

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = loadOut;
    function loadOut () {
        document.getElementById('accomplishments').className
        document.getElementById('accomplishments').className + 'animated fadeOutLeft';
    }
</script>
```

Now I am open to using JavaScript, JQuery, SASS, LESS, CSS, and/or any other method. The desired outcome is to get the animation to occur when a person clicks a site internal link. The goal is to make this look more like a app than a webpage.

Comment: don't you need a return value for the function tied to onbeforeunload even if it is return null?

Comment: I don't know, I just found that code online, I have little idea what that function does because the documentation is a bit mixed and reviews say that chrome doesn't support that except for alerts, Only mozilla works, IE never works with it, etc.

Comment: sorry that didn't work.  I deleted my answer as not to confuse people.  maybe try adding an event listener to the window for the "onbeforeunload" event and use your loadOut function as the event handler

Comment: After profiling it, I found that if I added a window.alert() to the function, it (the browser) blocks the window.alert()

Comment: I am now using the following method that returns an alert:
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return 'Leaving Blog Page. Are you sure?';
   });

Comment: But it doesn't allow me to add a class

Comment: $("#accomplishments").addClass("animated fadeOutLeft"); doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems with chrome page transition too, and decided to use the plugin [smoothState.js](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js#onbefore) . Maybe this could help. An example [here](http://miguel-perez.github.io/smoothState.js/index.html).

Comment: I actually found a better way to do this altogether. I built my transitions from the ground up and developed my css alongside my code. This way the code words with my page. It isn't a universal solution, but programming rarely has those.